# executing script on remote host using ssh does not return

Tags: shell-script, ssh, remote, interactive

We have several scripts on remotehost which we trigger from my localhost using ssh like below.

```
ssh remuser@remhost sh /web/bin/stop.sh
```

We had OS patching activity this weekend post which the above ssh command never returns and feels like it is hung or waiting for input.

It may be difficult to get details regarding what patch was applied to the OS.

Here are the details of the stop.sh

```
cat stop.sh
exec /usr/bin/java -jar /web/service.jar -DLOG_PATH=/web/logs --server.address=10.23.41.211 --server.port=10500 --spring.profiles.active=dev >> /web/logs/boot.log
exit 0;
```

First, we tried this solution from this forum but it does not return.

```
ssh remuser@remhost 'sh /web/bin/stop.sh my.jar dev &> /dev/null < /dev/null'
```

Debug output of `ssh -vv` when it freezes and does not return is below:

```
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_read (i0 o0 sock -1 wfd 4 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
```

We then tried the below and the ssh started returning but was unable to run the script on the remote host.

```
ssh -fN remuser@remhost sh /web/bin/stop.sh my.jar dev
```

Note: `ssh remuser@remhost id` does return and works fine. Other scripts also work fine.

The issue is only with the scripts that have `<or <<` or `> or >>` where the control returns back to the invoker host.

Can you please suggest?

Note: There is no reason to debug the scripts. They are not the cause of issue as all the script are different and some very simple.

Comment: If you don't know what is causing the problem, how can you be so certain it isn't something in the scripts that's triggering it?

Comment: Does `ssh remuser@remhost id` return a value? (Not interested in what the value is, just whether it returns one.) If it does then the problem is in your script. This is basic diagnosis 101

Comment: yes `ssh remuser@remhost id` returns value. Also update the original post with `ssh -vv` debug output

Comment: I suggest to show the code of the script `/web/bin/stop.sh` (or some other script that reproduces the problem).  What exactly means "was unable to run the script on the remote host"? Please copy&paste the exact error message to your question.

Comment: @Bodo i shared by updating the original post

Comment: Any clue @Bodo?

Comment: "_`ssh remuser@remhost id` returns value"_ so the problem isn't with the remote connection. Therefore it must be with your script(s).

Comment: @roaima ssh service on remote hosts was patch by OS team after which we started seeing this issue with no changes to our scripts.

Comment: I updated all information from the comments to the original post.

Comment: It doesn't matter that the scripts haven't changed. There are two parts to the commands you've shown us: the `ssh` connection and the script. You've confirmed the connection works, leaving only one other option - your scripts

Comment: @roaima fine however, i m looking for a solution be it with ssh or with the script code that I shared.

Comment: Sure. Basic debugging once more. 1. What gets written to `/web/logs/boot.log` since the updates, and how has it changed from before the updates? 2. What updates were applied? If the team that applied the updates doesn't know what they are doing they should be sent for training. (cont'd)

Comment: 3. What happens if you log in through `ssh` interactively, and then execute `java -jar /web/service.jar -DLOG_PATH=/web/logs --server.address=10.23.41.211 --server.port=10500 --spring.profiles.active=dev`? More importantly, does it do what you expect, and if not what does it do instead? Can you get someone to interpret the difference?

Comment: @roaima  What happens if you log in through ssh interactively, and then execute java -> it works fine and does what it needs to do i.e. starts a java process when executed locally on the remote host command line.

Comment: What exactly got changed in the "OS patches" you mentioned?   was `sshd` upgraded or reconfigured? was `sh` upgraded or replaced (e.g. switching from bash to dash as the default /bin/sh). Was java upgraded? Or any of the java libs that your `/web/service.jar` uses?  Was service.jar itself updated?

Comment: Does the command `/usr/bin/java -jar /web/service.jar ...` return after a short time? If I understand your `ssh` command and script correct I think `ssh` will wait until the Java program ends. Your script `stop.sh` doesn't seem to use the arguments `my.jar` and `dev`. You should make sure that the commands and script code are consistent and that you copy&paste (not retype) a script you have really run.

Comment: Yes Java command returns after 2 minutes. Also you can ignore the arguments as I have hard-coded in my stop.sh  script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following helped resolve the issue and now the control comes back while the script gets executed on the target host.

```
ssh -f -n remuser@remhost 'sh -c /web/bin/stop.sh my.jar dev'
```

Comment: "-f" option worked